# Is it safe to add to a waitgroup from multiple goroutines?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

If I have multiple go routines concurrently adding and calling done to a waitgroup. Is this safe from a concurrency perspective? Most waitgroup examples I've seen keep the adding in a single go-routine that calls/creates the others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calling `Done` from multiple routines is safe and is the recommended usage of `WaitGroup` per [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup). The reason to call `Add` from the goroutine that spawns more routines is not because `Add` is not thread-safe, it is because of the possibility that code like this:

```
for ... {
    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        defer wg.Done()
        ...
    }()
}
wg.Wait()
```

May get to the `wg.Wait()` before any of the calls to `Add` are executed, when the counter is still at zero, thereby defeating the purpose. The execution order of concurrent code is non-deterministic.

Comment: the "add" go-routine creates the "done" go-routine and I can just add(1)  at startup (and then have my "stop" function call an extra done then call wait), so looks like I'll be fine. Thanks! I'll accept in a couple minutes.

Comment: That's one way to do it, but less clear than the recommended style used in the example in the docs.

Comment: Well it using a the httpserver which creates a new routine per request. I suppose this where channels could be used

Comment: This seems like a very irregular design and worthy of some additional thought. Graceful shutdown of a server is not a simple matter of applying a WaitGroup, and a channel definitely isn't going to help. You likely don't want to call `Wait` at all until a shutdown has been requested, in which case you can call `Add` and `Done` both in the handler routine, and call `Wait` after you've stopped your `Listener`.

Comment: yes, the add(1) is not required as wait is not called until after the httpserver stops. My stop function closes the server then the handler. The running server keeping the program from preternaturally exiting was the part I was missing. Thanks again!

Comment: `WaitGroup` uses the `atomic` package on `Add` so it should be threadsafe, but there are two `panic`s in the code that are confusing and I can't make out how they would trigger. `panic("sync: WaitGroup misuse: Add called concurrently with Wait")` https://golang.org/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L77 and https://golang.org/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L88

Comment: Yes, calling `Add` while there are routines blocked on a call to `Wait` is a misuse. But, if the handlers are calling `Add` at the very start and the listener is stopped before calling `Wait`, this should be a non-issue.